ECharts: Candlestick width not increasing on zoom with time xAxis and 'empty' filterMode
Using ECharts, I've noticed that candlesticks don't widen when zooming in with these settings:

xAxis type is 'time'
dataZoom filterMode is 'empty'
Series type is 'candlestick'

var option = {
  xAxis: { type: "time" },
  yAxis: { type: "value", scale: true },
  series: [
    {
      type: "candlestick",
      data: ohlcData,
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: "inside",
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: "empty",
    },
    {
      type: "slider",
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: "empty",
    },
  ],
};



var dom = document.getElementById("chart-container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};
var option;

// Generate time series data
const baseDate = new Date(2023, 0, 1);
const ohlcData = [];
const dateData = [];
let prevClose = 50;
const volatility = 0.02;
for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  const date = new Date(baseDate);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
  dateData.push(date);
  const dailyReturn =
    (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() - 1.5) * volatility;
  const open = prevClose * (1 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.001);
  const close = open * (1 + dailyReturn);
  const high = Math.max(open, close) * (1 + Math.random() * 0.005);
  const low = Math.min(open, close) * (1 - Math.random() * 0.005);
  ohlcData.push([open, close, low, high]);
  prevClose = close;
}

// Create chart
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: "time",
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: "value",
    scale: true,
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: "candlestick",
      data: ohlcData.map((item, index) => [dateData[index], ...item]),
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: "inside",
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: "empty",
    },
    {
      type: "slider",
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: "empty",
    },
  ],
};

myChart.setOption(option);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart-container"></div>



How can I make candlesticks widen on zoom while keeping the time xAxis and empty filterMode?

Note: apache/echarts #20242 - github.com

Solution
You can insert a hook function into the dataZoom event, where you can query the current data of the chart.
// Listening to the zoom event and dynamically change the candlestick width
myChart.on('dataZoom', function(params) {
  const startValue = myChart.getModel().option.dataZoom[0].startValue;
  const endValue = myChart.getModel().option.dataZoom[0].endValue;
  // Find indexes from dateData by startValue and endValue
  const startIndex = dateData.findIndex(item => new Date(item) >= new Date(startValue));
  const endIndex = dateData.findIndex(item => new Date(item) >= new Date(endValue));

  // Calculate a visible item count by indexes
  const visibleDataCount = (endIndex !== -1 && startIndex !== -1) ? endIndex - startIndex : 0;

  // Dynamically calculate new width, use grid-width, gap, candlestick visible count
  
  // Get the chart container width
  const chartContainerWidth = dom.clientWidth;
  // Retrieve grid configuration
  const gridConfig = myChart.getOption().grid[0] || {};
  const gridLeftPercent = parseFloat(gridConfig.left) || 0;
  const gridRightPercent = parseFloat(gridConfig.right) || 0;
  // Convert percentages to pixels
  const gridLeftPx = (gridLeftPercent / 100) * chartContainerWidth;
  const gridRightPx = (gridRightPercent / 100) * chartContainerWidth;
  // Calculate the width of the plotting area
  const gridWidth = chartContainerWidth - gridLeftPx - gridRightPx;
  
  // Gap between data
  const gap = chartContainerWidth / visibleDataCount / 3
  
  const MAXIMUM_BAR_WIDTH = 50
  // BAR_WIDTH = (GRID_WIDTH - SUM_GAP_WIDTHS) / COUNT_BAR
  const currentBarWidth = (gridWidth - (visibleDataCount - 1) * gap) / visibleDataCount
  // Maximum or Current width will min
  const newBarWidth = Math.min(MAXIMUM_BAR_WIDTH, currentBarWidth)
  
  // Update the candlestick width
  myChart.setOption({
    series: [{
      type: 'candlestick',
      barWidth: newBarWidth // New candlestick width
    }]
  });
});

Explanation of the calculation I set up
We will check the minimum and maximum dates selected in the dataZoom. We will find the indices in the dateData array closest to these two dates.
From these two indices, we can calculate how many data points (bars) are currently visible on the chart. Then, we calculate the space allocated for displaying the bars (grid). Based on the available space and the number of bars, you can adjust the width of the bars as needed.
I also added a gap variable to ensure the bars do not touch each other. I set a maximum width for the bars at 50, so even if the formula calculates a larger number, the width cannot exceed 50.
Example


var dom = document.getElementById("chart-container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};
var option;

// Generate time series data
const baseDate = new Date(2023, 0, 1);
const ohlcData = [];
const dateData = [];
let prevClose = 50;
const volatility = 0.02;
for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  const date = new Date(baseDate);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
  dateData.push(date);
  const dailyReturn =
    (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() - 1.5) * volatility;
  const open = prevClose * (1 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.001);
  const close = open * (1 + dailyReturn);
  const high = Math.max(open, close) * (1 + Math.random() * 0.005);
  const low = Math.min(open, close) * (1 - Math.random() * 0.005);
  ohlcData.push([open, close, low, high]);
  prevClose = close;
}

// Create chart
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: "time",
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: "value",
    scale: true,
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: "candlestick",
      data: ohlcData.map((item, index) => [dateData[index], ...item]),
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: "inside",
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: "empty",
    },
    {
      type: "slider",
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: "empty",
    },
  ],
};

myChart.setOption(option);

// Listening to the zoom event and dynamically change the candlestick width
myChart.on('dataZoom', function(params) {
  const startValue = myChart.getModel().option.dataZoom[0].startValue;
  const endValue = myChart.getModel().option.dataZoom[0].endValue;
  // Find indexes from dateData by startValue and endValue
  const startIndex = dateData.findIndex(item => new Date(item) >= new Date(startValue));
  const endIndex = dateData.findIndex(item => new Date(item) >= new Date(endValue));

  // Calculate a visible item count by indexes
  const visibleDataCount = (endIndex !== -1 && startIndex !== -1) ? endIndex - startIndex : 0;

  // Dynamically calculate new width, use grid-width, gap, candlestick visible count
  
  // Get the chart container width
  const chartContainerWidth = dom.clientWidth;
  // Retrieve grid configuration
  const gridConfig = myChart.getOption().grid[0] || {};
  const gridLeftPercent = parseFloat(gridConfig.left) || 0;
  const gridRightPercent = parseFloat(gridConfig.right) || 0;
  // Convert percentages to pixels
  const gridLeftPx = (gridLeftPercent / 100) * chartContainerWidth;
  const gridRightPx = (gridRightPercent / 100) * chartContainerWidth;
  // Calculate the width of the plotting area
  const gridWidth = chartContainerWidth - gridLeftPx - gridRightPx;
  
  // Gap between data
  const gap = chartContainerWidth / visibleDataCount / 3
  
  const MAXIMUM_BAR_WIDTH = 50
  // BAR_WIDTH = (GRID_WIDTH - SUM_GAP_WIDTHS) / COUNT_BAR
  const currentBarWidth = (gridWidth - (visibleDataCount - 1) * gap) / visibleDataCount
  // Maximum or Current width will min
  const newBarWidth = Math.min(MAXIMUM_BAR_WIDTH, currentBarWidth)
  
  // Update the candlestick width
  myChart.setOption({
    series: [{
      type: 'candlestick',
      barWidth: newBarWidth // New candlestick width
    }]
  });
});
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 650px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart-container"></div>



